# how can i hide or show array data fetched from mongodb

Tags: php, html, mongodb

contacts'.''. '['.'contacts'.']'.'=>'.wordwrap(implode("\n", $contacts), 136, "\n", true).'$("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#demo").toggle();});$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#demo1").toggle();});'. ''

Comment: here when fetched record only one then toggle is working for contacts field otherwise its not working why

Comment: Your question is not clear to any one.

Comment: <button id="btn1">notificationss</button>'.'<div id="demo1" style="display:true;">'. '['.'notifications'.']'.'=>'.wordwrap(implode("\n", $notifications), 136, "\n", true).'</div><script>$("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#demo").toggle();});$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#demo1").toggle();});</script>'. '</pre></body>'

Comment: Now what is this? Edit your question and make it understandable otherwise it is closed as per the community rules

Comment: I want to apply toggle for  the contacts  field which contains the data fetched from database.But it works only when one record presented otherwise its not working

Comment: What do you mean by not working ?

Comment: i mean when i click on the button if the table consists of only one record then i can be able to show or hide the information otherwise its not behave like that

Comment: Your code is not in the form to understand by some one and help you